# Specifying a db function in an insert statement in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, insert, zend-db

I have something like this:

```
$data = array('username' => 'John', 'password' => 'john123');
$table = new Zend_Db_Table('users');
$table->insert($data);
```

But I want it to include a hashing function to the password, so the sql is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('John', PASSWORD('john123'));
```

How can I do that, elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array('username' => 'John', 'password' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SHA1(john123)');
```

Comment: May also work without the object in some cases (like in where() function or select statement - Zend is looking for brackets there to convert the value into function...).

Comment: I ended up having to do `Zend_Db_Expr('SHA1('.$db->quote('john123').')')`